# Why selectable list of items doesn't work in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

The jdango view returns list of components and the li items contain html code saved in `{{ component.html }}` variable.

html file:

```
<ol id="app_components">
  {% for component in components %}
    <li id="{{ component.id }}" class="component">
    {{ component.html|safe }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

js file:

```
$( "#app_components" ).selectable();
```

css file:

```
.ui-selecting {
  background: grey;
}
.ui-selected {
  background: blue;
}
```

I don't know why not works. Any idea ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change strategy, changed jQuery UI selectable to sortable [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)